# What HTML Error Messages can be customised?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

What messages can be customised in .htaccess? I understand that Error 400, 401, 403, 404, etc. can be customised. However some client-side errors cannot be customised, such as Error 504 (Gateway Time-out).

So, is there a list of errors that can be customised in .htaccess? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the documentation: Customized error responses can be defined for any HTTP status code designated as an error condition - that is, any 4xx or 5xx status. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: Please, don't ask questions, answers on which you can find through the google, just duplicating your question to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what Sergio Ivanuzzo said, you might want to refer to the official documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

According to the documentation, "customized error responses can be defined for any HTTP status code designated as an error condition - that is, any 4xx or 5xx status".

Hope this helps ☺